# Запуск проекта на Django на сервере Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, django

Почему проект запускается на локалхосте? Debug = False, Allowed Hosts заполнил. прописываю в терминале python3 manage.py runserver, запускается на 127.0.0.1. Как запустить на хосте сервера?

Comment: `Allowed Hosts` очевидно про другое, у вас проблема в *binding* host.

Comment: как это решить?

Comment: Понятия не имею, не понятно ни что за проект, ни как он настраивается, ни где почитать документацию. По-хорошему, это ваша домашняя работа *перед тем как задавать вопрос*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использую сервера Google Cloud, в сетевом интерфейсе вместо внешнего айпи установлен внутренний. Нужно решить эту проблему и все заработает. Ну и еще при запуске джанго указаывать айпи.
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000